# Ggplot time series representation highlight each group outgreying the rest (facet_wrap + geom_line?)

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have this data:

```
    structure(list(idx = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L), value = c(-0.63023548014462, -0.225487408228219, -0.0788347385823727, 
-0.742730897851288, 0.144947779830545, 1.03189769713208, 0.290215650573373, 
0.957113281823695, 0.893150312826037, 0.993117796257138, 1.09846593020484, 
0.576255449093878, 1.09728207532316, 0.458922276739031, 0.269486639183015, 
0.976583545096219, 1.92938052397221, 1.38103144615889, 1.27064990438521, 
0.420608753804117, 0.74440627079457, 0.519505355972797, 1.19328370969743, 
0.494286591187119, 0.188831089064479, 0.166377551853657, -0.535128722433001, 
-0.821003542281687, 0.104284554254264, -0.630971439182758, -1.61014238838106, 
-2.28085790434852, -1.66047361539677, -0.922751541715115, -0.894188015721738, 
-0.639795442577451, 0.0490625635720789, -0.381196287926286, -0.0467449924908578, 
-0.745805488433689, -0.298714850097895, 0.045283006504178, -0.904616280458868, 
-1.10241420473903, -1.70246114488691, -0.989411143120378, -0.0463802861049771, 
-0.398935412522405, 0.0674474542029202, -0.252416065428406, 0.701094303745776, 
0.495127127505839, 0.255124886054546, 0.37590014655143, 0.303516504820436, 
-0.302929841913283, -0.449043036438525, -1.26299266144633, -2.03237440763041, 
-2.15231109922752, -2.7504416401498, -2.89516349462792, -1.93396353116259, 
-1.27611928014085, -1.70217157015577, -1.51033777650446, -0.712393884081393, 
-0.805639883503318, -1.51080432487652, -2.25345035968348, -3.20413768431172, 
-2.73151493445039, -2.98479780554771, -2.83604392455891, -2.18538789777085, 
-1.55799655010924, -0.812603869475424, -1.59149407036602, -0.686093596741557, 
-0.548089434858412, 0.680742355529219, 1.57127851666883, 0.661208916921169, 
1.17797473212704, 0.771750728134066, 1.0738596059382, 0.243839174509048, 
1.19480132451281, 0.222051187418401, 0.299790090881288, 1.23135369410738, 
0.433500582352281, -0.0529967322945595, 0.737297710031271, 0.513186091557145, 
1.10175698110834, 0.8005505008623, 0.0780391143634915, 0.379057081416249, 
0.467065697070211, -0.63023548014462, -0.225487408228219, -0.0788347385823727, 
-0.742730897851288, 0.144947779830545, 1.03189769713208, 0.290215650573373, 
0.957113281823695, 0.893150312826037, 0.993117796257138, 1.09846593020484, 
0.576255449093878, 1.09728207532316, 0.458922276739031, 0.269486639183015, 
0.976583545096219, 1.92938052397221, 1.38103144615889, 1.27064990438521, 
0.420608753804117, 0.74440627079457, 0.519505355972797, 1.19328370969743, 
0.494286591187119, 0.188831089064479, 0.166377551853657, -0.535128722433001, 
-0.821003542281687, 0.104284554254264, -0.630971439182758, -1.61014238838106, 
-2.28085790434852, -1.66047361539677, -0.922751541715115, -0.894188015721738, 
-0.639795442577451, 0.0490625635720789, -0.381196287926286, -0.0467449924908578, 
-0.745805488433689, -0.298714850097895, 0.045283006504178, -0.904616280458868, 
-1.10241420473903, -1.70246114488691, -0.989411143120378, -0.0463802861049771, 
-0.398935412522405, 0.0674474542029202, -0.252416065428406, 0.701094303745776, 
0.495127127505839, 0.255124886054546, 0.37590014655143, 0.303516504820436, 
-0.302929841913283, -0.449043036438525, -1.26299266144633, -2.03237440763041, 
-2.15231109922752, -2.7504416401498, -2.89516349462792, -1.93396353116259, 
-1.27611928014085, -1.70217157015577, -1.51033777650446, -0.712393884081393, 
-0.805639883503318, -1.51080432487652, -2.25345035968348, -3.20413768431172, 
-2.73151493445039, -2.98479780554771, -2.83604392455891, -2.18538789777085, 
-1.55799655010924, -0.812603869475424, -1.59149407036602, -0.686093596741557, 
-0.548089434858412, 0.680742355529219, 1.57127851666883, 0.661208916921169, 
1.17797473212704, 0.771750728134066, 1.0738596059382, 0.243839174509048, 
1.19480132451281, 0.222051187418401, 0.299790090881288, 1.23135369410738, 
0.433500582352281, -0.0529967322945595, 0.737297710031271, 0.513186091557145, 
1.10175698110834, 0.8005505008623, 0.0780391143634915, 0.379057081416249, 
0.467065697070211, -0.63023548014462, -0.225487408228219, -0.0788347385823727, 
-0.742730897851288, 0.144947779830545, 1.03189769713208, 0.290215650573373, 
0.957113281823695, 0.893150312826037, 0.993117796257138, 1.09846593020484, 
0.576255449093878, 1.09728207532316, 0.458922276739031, 0.269486639183015, 
0.976583545096219, 1.92938052397221, 1.38103144615889, 1.27064990438521, 
0.420608753804117, 0.74440627079457, 0.519505355972797, 1.19328370969743, 
0.494286591187119, 0.188831089064479, 0.166377551853657, -0.535128722433001, 
-0.821003542281687, 0.104284554254264, -0.630971439182758, -1.61014238838106, 
-2.28085790434852, -1.66047361539677, -0.922751541715115, -0.894188015721738, 
-0.639795442577451, 0.0490625635720789, -0.381196287926286, -0.0467449924908578, 
-0.745805488433689, -0.298714850097895, 0.045283006504178, -0.904616280458868, 
-1.10241420473903, -1.70246114488691, -0.989411143120378, -0.0463802861049771, 
-0.398935412522405, 0.0674474542029202, -0.252416065428406, 0.701094303745776, 
0.495127127505839, 0.255124886054546, 0.37590014655143, 0.303516504820436, 
-0.302929841913283, -0.449043036438525, -1.26299266144633, -2.03237440763041, 
-2.15231109922752, -2.7504416401498, -2.89516349462792, -1.93396353116259, 
-1.27611928014085, -1.70217157015577, -1.51033777650446, -0.712393884081393, 
-0.805639883503318, -1.51080432487652, -2.25345035968348, -3.20413768431172, 
-2.73151493445039, -2.98479780554771, -2.83604392455891, -2.18538789777085, 
-1.55799655010924, -0.812603869475424, -1.59149407036602, -0.686093596741557, 
-0.548089434858412, 0.680742355529219, 1.57127851666883, 0.661208916921169, 
1.17797473212704, 0.771750728134066, 1.0738596059382, 0.243839174509048, 
1.19480132451281, 0.222051187418401, 0.299790090881288, 1.23135369410738, 
0.433500582352281, -0.0529967322945595, 0.737297710031271, 0.513186091557145, 
1.10175698110834, 0.8005505008623, 0.0780391143634915, 0.379057081416249, 
0.467065697070211, -0.63023548014462, -0.225487408228219, -0.0788347385823727, 
-0.742730897851288, 0.144947779830545, 1.03189769713208, 0.290215650573373, 
0.957113281823695, 0.893150312826037, 0.993117796257138, 1.09846593020484, 
0.576255449093878, 1.09728207532316, 0.458922276739031, 0.269486639183015, 
0.976583545096219, 1.92938052397221, 1.38103144615889, 1.27064990438521, 
0.420608753804117, 0.74440627079457, 0.519505355972797, 1.19328370969743, 
0.494286591187119, 0.188831089064479, 0.166377551853657, -0.535128722433001, 
-0.821003542281687, 0.104284554254264, -0.630971439182758, -1.61014238838106, 
-2.28085790434852, -1.66047361539677, -0.922751541715115, -0.894188015721738, 
-0.639795442577451, 0.0490625635720789, -0.381196287926286, -0.0467449924908578, 
-0.745805488433689, -0.298714850097895, 0.045283006504178, -0.904616280458868, 
-1.10241420473903, -1.70246114488691, -0.989411143120378, -0.0463802861049771, 
-0.398935412522405, 0.0674474542029202, -0.252416065428406, 0.701094303745776, 
0.495127127505839, 0.255124886054546, 0.37590014655143, 0.303516504820436, 
-0.302929841913283, -0.449043036438525, -1.26299266144633, -2.03237440763041, 
-2.15231109922752, -2.7504416401498, -2.89516349462792, -1.93396353116259, 
-1.27611928014085, -1.70217157015577, -1.51033777650446, -0.712393884081393, 
-0.805639883503318, -1.51080432487652, -2.25345035968348, -3.20413768431172, 
-2.73151493445039, -2.98479780554771, -2.83604392455891, -2.18538789777085, 
-1.55799655010924, -0.812603869475424, -1.59149407036602, -0.686093596741557, 
-0.548089434858412, 0.680742355529219, 1.57127851666883, 0.661208916921169, 
1.17797473212704, 0.771750728134066, 1.0738596059382, 0.243839174509048, 
1.19480132451281, 0.222051187418401, 0.299790090881288, 1.23135369410738, 
0.433500582352281, -0.0529967322945595, 0.737297710031271, 0.513186091557145, 
1.10175698110834, 0.8005505008623, 0.0780391143634915, 0.379057081416249, 
0.467065697070211, -0.63023548014462, -0.225487408228219, -0.0788347385823727, 
-0.742730897851288, 0.144947779830545, 1.03189769713208, 0.290215650573373, 
0.957113281823695, 0.893150312826037, 0.993117796257138, 1.09846593020484, 
0.576255449093878, 1.09728207532316, 0.458922276739031, 0.269486639183015, 
0.976583545096219, 1.92938052397221, 1.38103144615889, 1.27064990438521, 
0.420608753804117, 0.74440627079457, 0.519505355972797, 1.19328370969743, 
0.494286591187119, 0.188831089064479, 0.166377551853657, -0.535128722433001, 
-0.821003542281687, 0.104284554254264, -0.630971439182758, -1.61014238838106, 
-2.28085790434852, -1.66047361539677, -0.922751541715115, -0.894188015721738, 
-0.639795442577451, 0.0490625635720789, -0.381196287926286, -0.0467449924908578, 
-0.745805488433689, -0.298714850097895, 0.045283006504178, -0.904616280458868, 
-1.10241420473903, -1.70246114488691, -0.989411143120378, -0.0463802861049771, 
-0.398935412522405, 0.0674474542029202, -0.252416065428406, 0.701094303745776, 
0.495127127505839, 0.255124886054546, 0.37590014655143, 0.303516504820436, 
-0.302929841913283, -0.449043036438525, -1.26299266144633, -2.03237440763041, 
-2.15231109922752, -2.7504416401498, -2.89516349462792, -1.93396353116259, 
-1.27611928014085, -1.70217157015577, -1.51033777650446, -0.712393884081393, 
-0.805639883503318, -1.51080432487652, -2.25345035968348, -3.20413768431172, 
-2.73151493445039, -2.98479780554771, -2.83604392455891, -2.18538789777085, 
-1.55799655010924, -0.812603869475424, -1.59149407036602, -0.686093596741557, 
-0.548089434858412, 0.680742355529219, 1.57127851666883, 0.661208916921169, 
1.17797473212704, 0.771750728134066, 1.0738596059382, 0.243839174509048, 
1.19480132451281, 0.222051187418401, 0.299790090881288, 1.23135369410738, 
0.433500582352281, -0.0529967322945595, 0.737297710031271, 0.513186091557145, 
1.10175698110834, 0.8005505008623, 0.0780391143634915, 0.379057081416249, 
0.467065697070211, -0.63023548014462, -0.225487408228219, -0.0788347385823727, 
-0.742730897851288, 0.144947779830545, 1.03189769713208, 0.290215650573373, 
0.957113281823695, 0.893150312826037, 0.993117796257138, 1.09846593020484, 
0.576255449093878, 1.09728207532316, 0.458922276739031, 0.269486639183015, 
0.976583545096219, 1.92938052397221, 1.38103144615889, 1.27064990438521, 
0.420608753804117, 0.74440627079457, 0.519505355972797, 1.19328370969743, 
0.494286591187119, 0.188831089064479, 0.166377551853657, -0.535128722433001, 
-0.821003542281687, 0.104284554254264, -0.630971439182758, -1.61014238838106, 
-2.28085790434852, -1.66047361539677, -0.922751541715115, -0.894188015721738, 
-0.639795442577451, 0.0490625635720789, -0.381196287926286, -0.0467449924908578, 
-0.745805488433689, -0.298714850097895, 0.045283006504178, -0.904616280458868, 
-1.10241420473903, -1.70246114488691, -0.989411143120378, -0.0463802861049771, 
-0.398935412522405, 0.0674474542029202, -0.252416065428406, 0.701094303745776, 
0.495127127505839, 0.255124886054546, 0.37590014655143, 0.303516504820436, 
-0.302929841913283, -0.449043036438525, -1.26299266144633, -2.03237440763041, 
-2.15231109922752, -2.7504416401498, -2.89516349462792, -1.93396353116259, 
-1.27611928014085, -1.70217157015577, -1.51033777650446, -0.712393884081393, 
-0.805639883503318, -1.51080432487652, -2.25345035968348, -3.20413768431172, 
-2.73151493445039, -2.98479780554771, -2.83604392455891, -2.18538789777085, 
-1.55799655010924, -0.812603869475424, -1.59149407036602, -0.686093596741557, 
-0.548089434858412, 0.680742355529219, 1.57127851666883, 0.661208916921169, 
1.17797473212704, 0.771750728134066, 1.0738596059382, 0.243839174509048, 
1.19480132451281, 0.222051187418401, 0.299790090881288, 1.23135369410738, 
0.433500582352281, -0.0529967322945595, 0.737297710031271, 0.513186091557145, 
1.10175698110834, 0.8005505008623, 0.0780391143634915, 0.379057081416249, 
0.467065697070211), type = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), flag = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE), col2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), levels = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-600L), class = "data.frame")
ggplot(d) +
  geom_line(aes(idx, value, colour = type))+
  facet_wrap(~type)

ggplot(data = data2, mapping = aes(x = idx, y = value,group=type, colour = colour2,alpha=colour2)) + # specify data, x-axis, y-axis and grouping variable
  geom_line(aes(colour=colour2),alpha=0.7) + # a line per group
  geom_point() + # points per group
  theme_hc() +  # a ggtheme, similar to your example
  theme(legend.position = "right", # move legend to the right hand side of the plot
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), # remove x axis title
        # axis.title.y = element_blank(), # remove y axis title
        legend.title = element_blank(), # remove legend title
        plot.title = element_text(size = 20, color = "gray40"), # change size and color of plot title
        plot.subtitle = element_text(color = "gray40"), # change color of subtitle
        plot.caption = element_text(color = "gray40", hjust = 0)) + # change color of caption and left-align
  scale_colour_manual(values=c('grey',"blue"))+
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.1,7))+
  scale_size_manual(values=c(1,2.2))+
  facet_wrap2(~col2,ncol=5,scales = 'free',axes='all',remove_labels = "x") + # facet wrap
  theme(legend.position = "none") + # remove legend, since not needed anymore in facet_wrap
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(4, "mm")) + # avoid overlapping of x axis text
  ylab("%")
```

[image]

The thing is that the lines in blue, are not specifically on top of the other ones, so when the line density is bigger, you can see grey lines crossing the blue one. How can I make highlighted lines to be on top?

Random text so it lets me publish:
The thing is that the lines in blue, are not specifically on top of the other ones, so when the line density is bigger, you can see grey lines crossing the blue one. How can I make highlighted lines to be on top?
The thing is that the lines in blue, are not specifically on top of the other ones, so when the line density is bigger, you can see grey lines crossing the blue one. How can I make highlighted lines to be on top?
The thing is that the lines in blue, are not specifically on top of the other ones, so when the line density is bigger, you can see grey lines crossing the blue one. How can I make highlighted lines to be on top?
The thing is that the lines in blue, are not specifically on top of the other ones, so when the line density is bigger, you can see grey lines crossing the blue one. How can I make highlighted lines to be on top?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the output of `dput(data2)`? At the moment this is not a reproducible example, and most of the code is not needed/irrelevant. Just the `dput(data2)` and your last `ggplot(..)` code should be sufficient

Comment: Done. I put all that text because I transformed data from data to data2, but I am not sure that was necessary. But that was the only way I could think of to use facet_wrap and plot all the lines.